# Summarize file sizes of a directory structure?

Tags: ls, file-size

I have written a small backup script with `rsync`. I would like to monitor its progress by comparing the total file sizes on the source and destination directories. `du` Is inaccurate because it measures the disk usage, not the file size, and the disk usage varies between file systems.

How can I summarize the file sizes of an entire directory structure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the `--apparent-size` option for `du` will do what you are after:

```
--apparent-size
       print apparent sizes,  rather  than  disk  usage;  although  the
       apparent  size is usually smaller, it may be larger due to holes
       in (`sparse') files, internal  fragmentation,  indirect  blocks,
       and the like
```

That should remove the dependence on file system block sizes or other metadata.

Comment: It's way better, but the result still differs a little bit - do you have an educated guess why?

Comment: Perhaps the directories themselves (as opposed to the files stored in the directories) report different sizes on the two file systems?